# UIGestureRecognizer multiple pan gestures

Tags: iphone, uigesturerecognizer

How do I enable multiple touch in UIPanGestureRecognizer?

When I debug UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged I see that multiple touches are handled like single gesture. What should I do to handle the multiple touch separately?

```
 UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer;

panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanFrom:)];
panRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1; panRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 5; 
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
```

Comment: I am trying to achieve something like fruit ninja touches. How you can use many fingers and each finger acts like a separate sword?

Comment: By not using gesture recognizers at all... Fruit ninja probably detects raw touches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create a different gesture recognizer with different minimum = maximum = [number here] properties set.

Comment: So this means I can't have multiple separate single finger gesture recognizers?

Comment: I am trying to achieve something like fruit ninja touches. How you can use many fingers and each finger acts like a separate sword?

Comment: you will have to access the actual UITouch objects and then figure them out. Theyr

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This reminds me that I can loop thru the individual UITouch objects.

Answer (score 0):

I think [minimumNumberOfTouches and maximumNumberOfTouches](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) should solve the problem.

Comment: I have flowed your advice, but don't see any change in the behavior.



`UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer;
    
panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanFrom:)];
panRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1; panRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 5; 
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];`